# How to 'configure' navigation with Android Navigation Component to have different behaviour between back and up?

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I have two destinations A (Master) and B (Detail).
I have the following actions:

- A to B
- B to B (next item)

This works fine, but it's the `up` and `back` behaviour I'm just not getting right.

When I get from A to B and I press either `back` or `up` I go back to A.
This is working as expected.
But when I have done the following navigation: A -> B -> B I need `back` to go to the previous B and up to go to A.

How do I configure my NavGraph in such a way that this happens?

**To be clear, with `back` I mean the 'device' back button, and with `up` i mean the button in the `ActionBar`**

Comment: Can you explain what is B->B they are separate screen's(Fragment??) how can you navigate from B to B? share the code of your nav_graph and SS(if possible!!).
And Action onBackPressed and NavigateUp both work similarly

Comment: B -> B means it should create a new instance of the same type of page. You navigate to it by going to the 'next' item.

Comment: can you share code of nav_graph?